# ¿Cómo se traduce el dicho "march to a different drummer" al español?

Tags: traducción, modismos

Alguien que "marches to the beat of a different drummer" es alguien que hace cosas en una forma no normal, no convencional. ¿Hay alguna expresión similar en español?

Wiktionary tiene una traducción literal, pero no la confío: [March to the beat of a different drum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/march_to_the_beat_of_a_different_drum).

---

Someone who "marches to the beat of a different drummer" is someone who does things in abnormal, unconventional ways.  Is there a similar expression in Spanish?

Wiktionary provides a literal translation, but I don't trust it: [March to the beat of a different drum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/march_to_the_beat_of_a_different_drum).

Comment: "March to the beat of a different drummer" not only says that someone does things differently, but implies that someone's character or internal clock is fundamentally different than most. Normally this phrase applies to people whose thought processes are noticeably different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know this English expression, so I am first writing down the explanation I found of it:

> [march to (the beat of) a different drummer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/march+to+a+different+drummer)
>
> Fig. to believe in a different set of principles. *John is marching to
>   a different drummer, and he doesn't associate with us anymore.*

To me, this sounds like something I would say:

- Ir a lo suyo

Or, more often but in an informal context -at least in Spain-:

- Ir a su bola

There is also a nice, idiomatic way:

- Hacer de su capa un sayo

Which is explained as:

> obrar alguien según su propio albedrío y con libertad en cosas o
>   asuntos que a él sólo pertenecen o atañen”, según leemos en Del Hecho
>   al Dicho, de Gregorio Doval (Ediciones del Prado, 1995)

and more info in ["¿Qué significa hacer de tu capa un sayo?"](http://www.estandarte.com/noticias/idioma-espanol/que-significa-hacer-de-tu-capa-un-sayo_1435.html).

Comment: +1 for "hacer de su capa un sayo". Sounds beautiful and people won't expect it from a foreigner.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente yo no he usado ni oído la traducción que en wiktionary se sugiere.
Lo que sí solemos decir es "hace las cosas a su manera".

Una expresión con un significado distinto pero que tiene cierta similitud a "march to a different drummer" es "esto ya es otra canción".

Answer (score 1):

En España, al menos por mi zona tenemos dos formas para referirnos a alguien que hace las cosas de manera diferente ya sea de manera temporal o no.

Decimos;

- "Ir con el paso cambiado" - Ejem. Ese va con el paso cambiado ó Juan hoy esta con el paso cambiado.
- "Ir con ritmo cambiado" - Ejem. Ten cuidado, no te acerques mucho que ese tiene el ritmo cambiado.

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos

Diego M.